# Kibana docker with TestContainer fails to start with "Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes."

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, testcontainers

I am trying to build a test container for Kibana to use it with Elasticsearch Test Container. According to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html) I just need to set `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS` environment variable for a Kibana docker to start it successfully. However, I can confirm that when I try to pass Elasticsearch container in a form of `http://localhost:62084/`it accepts the url, but Kibana container fails to start. When I check logs I could see the following entry:

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-08-03T07:59:34+00:00","tags":["error","savedobjects-service"],"pid":952,"message":"Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes."}
```

I can check the docker and see that the kibana.yml config shows the following value:

```
server.host: "0"
elasticsearch.hosts: [ "http://elasticsearch:9200" ]
monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true
```

So it looks like for some reason the `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS` variable was not effective.

You could find the code snippet for how I am setting Kibana testContainer using a Generic TestContainer below.

```
private static final int KIBANA_DEFAULT_PORT = 5601;

public KibanaContainer withElasticsearch(Network network, String elasticHostUrl) {
    withNetwork(network);
    withEnv("ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS", elasticHostUrl);
    setWaitStrategy(new HttpWaitStrategy()
        .forPort(KIBANA_DEFAULT_PORT)
        .forStatusCodeMatching(response -> response == HTTP_OK || response == HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
        .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(120)));
    return self();
  }
```